# Can I reset "tips" for documentation?

Tags: support, feature-request, documentation

I accidentally clicked a couple tips (floating blue dots) for documentation without reading their contents. The dots are gone after I closed the tip windows and I would like to get them back. Is there a way I can do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Documentation pages that offer help bubbles have a `(?)` icon towards the top of the page.  Clicking it toggles visibility of all the tips on the page.

[image]

^ [On the Documentation index page, for example](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation)

Comment: :P That explains why they keep on reappearing for me.